# Is the sequence $\{0,2,6,12,20,30,...,n(n+1)\}$ admissible for every natural $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Look here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple

for the definition of an admissible sequence.

I wonder if the sequence of differences of primes can be $\{0,2,4,6,8,...,2n\}$ for every natural nuber $n$. A weaker version is, that $p+(j-1)j$ is prime for every
$j$ with $1\le j\le n+1$.

For $n=7$, the smallest example for the weaker version is $11$, but $128981$
is the smallest example for the sequence $\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14\}$.

For $\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18\}$, the smallest example is $2426256797$.

The questions :

- Is the sequence $\{0,2,4,6,8,...2n\}$ of differences possible for every $n$ ?
- If not, is there at least an example for the weak version for every $n$ 
  (Equivalent : $\{0,2,6,12,20,30,...n(n+1)\}$ is admissible) ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530315/the-sequence-of-prime-gaps-is-never-strictly-monotonic?rq=1 is a related question.

Comment: But if I understand the question correctly, the OP ony looks for infinite strictly monotone sequences.

Comment: @zhoraster: The question is somewhat confusingly posed in that the notation differs from that in the linked Wikipedia article. Here the numbers are consecutive prime gaps, not differences with respect to the first prime in the tuple.

Comment: If the answer to the first question were "no", the answer to the second question couldn't be "yes", since if a sequence is inadmissible then there cannot be such prime constellations, irrespective of whether there are further primes in between.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is admissible for all $n$. Given $p$, we only need to consider $j\in[0,p-1]$ to get all residues mod $p$ that are covered by the sequence. Since $(p-j+1)(p-j)\equiv j(j-1)\bmod p$, most of the residues are doubly covered, and hence roughly half are uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

$(0,2,4)$ is already inadmissible according to the definition: it contains all residues mod 3. So the answer to the first question is negative. The second sequence is clearly admissible (it contains at most $p-2$ different non-zero residues mod $p$).

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of the question; please see my comment under the question.

Comment: That was my fault : I misinterpreted "admissible". I fixed the error.